# Are there limits to SSRS 2014 RDL files going over to SSRS 2008 (or 2012)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2014

Is there any incompatibility with reports developed in SQL Server SSRS 2014, and then exported to `.RDL` files that will be imported into SQL Server 2008?

Comment: If you need the option to downgrade, I suggest you develop using the oldest SSRS version.  The RDL is validated according to the schema referenced in the RDL, which older SSRS versions will know nothing about.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627465.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS Report Definition Language for SQL Server Reporting Services 2014 cannot be reliably imported into previous versions of SQL Server Reporting Services.

The Report Definition Schema files were modified in 2010; SSRS 2014 uses that version, which supports features that are not supported in the 2008 version of the schema.

The 2010 schema is at: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/

The 2008 schema is at: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/